# c言語、昇順並び替え。while(1)文がスキップされます。

Tags: c

c言語について、整数を入力し0が入力されたらそれらの整数を小さい順に表示するというプログラムの作成が大学の課題で出たのですがうまく動作しません。下のコードが自力で書いたもので、コンパイルは問題なくできたのですがwhile(1)文が完全にスキップされてしまいます。どの部分が悪いのかよく分かりません。初心者のためかなり拙いコードですがどなたかご教授の程よろしくお願いいたします。

プロトタイプ宣言ですが、下のコードの通りに書くよう言われました。

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUM 100

int AddArray(int Array[MAX_NUM], int data, int *data_num);

int main(void) {
    int Array[MAX_NUM];
    int data, a;
    int data_num = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("正整数");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        AddArray(Array, data, &data_num);
        data_num++;
        if (data == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("入力された数字は順に");
    for (a = 0; a < data_num - 1; a++) {
        printf("%d,",Array[a]);
    }
    if (a == data_num - 1) {
        printf("%d", Array[a]);
    }
    printf("です。\n");
}

int AddArray(int Array[MAX_NUM], int data, int *data_num) {
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    Array[*data_num] = data;
    if(*data_num != 0){
        for (i = 0; i < *data_num; i++) {
            for (j= *data_num - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (Array[*data_num] < Array[*data_num--]) {
                    temp = Array[*data_num--];
                    Array[*data_num--] = Array[*data_num];
                    Array[*data_num] = temp; 
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideone では問題なく実行できました。https://ideone.com/E2ivq6

Comment: data_numが0の時はその部分を実行しないようにif(data_num != 0)を付けたのですがそもそも書き方自体が間違っている感じでしょうか？

Comment: while ブロックの直前で data_num = 0 を代入しているので、もし、そのような if で while ブロックをスキップしようとしたら、常に while ブロック全体がスキップされます。data_num は while ブロックの中の処理で、文字数をカウントして初めて 0 以外の値がセットされるようになっているわけですから。

Comment: 「プロトタイプ宣言ですが、下のコードの通りに書くよう言われました。」というのは【関数 `AddArray` の型だけは指定されていてその中身は実装しろと言われている】という話かと思いますが，その場合，関数 `AddArray` の仕様を述べるべきではないでしょうか．戻り値も何に使うべきなのか謎ですし．

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。今後また質問する際に参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

「どの部分が悪いのかよく分かりません。」ということですが、

- まずプログラムの問題以前に「while(1)文が完全にスキップされてしまいます。」という認識あるいは質問内容が間違っていると思われます。

  - 例えばデバッグモードでコンパイルしてデバッガーで1ステップづつ実行してどのような状況であるかを確認しましょう。
    状況の正しい認識が無ければ何かをしようとしても遠回りになったり間違った方向に進んでしまうでしょう。
  - 実際には @y_waiwai さんの回答のように、while(1)文は実行されていて、その中で呼ばれる AddArray() の中で問題が発生しているのではないですか？
- そして data_num はどのようなデータであるか理解していますか？ その内容に沿ったプログラムを作成していますか？

  - 変数の名前と main() の中での使われ方から、入力されたデータの個数を表していると思われますが、そうであるならば AddArray() でポインタに対して同じ名前を使うのは本当は良くない設計ですね。
  - その辺が混同されているように見えるので、Array[*data_num--] という処理は、Array配列の入力されたデータ最後から順番に1つ手前のデータを取得しようと意図したものと思われますが、実際には main() の中で data_num が存在するアドレスより int型データ1つ分を減算したアドレスから取得したデータをインデックス値としてArray[]にアクセスしようとしています。
    [覚えておくべき優先順位の関係性③：インクリメント・デクリメントと間接参照演算子](https://monozukuri-c.com/langc-funclist-operator/#toc7)
    そのためにおかしなアドレスに存在したデータ内容によってはArray[]の範囲外をアクセスしようとして例外とかプログラム異常終了とかの現象が発生しているのではないでしょうか？
    データ内容に依存するのでたまたま異常にならず(あるいは何もしていないように見えて)終了する場合もあり得るでしょう。
  - また外側のforループでの終了判定や内側のforループの初期値設定に data_num を使っているのに、内側のforループの中でその値を書き変える処理をしていては、まともに動作しない可能性が高くなります。
  - 「プロトタイプ宣言ですが、下のコードの通りに書くよう言われました。」の対象が AddArray() ならば、ソートの処理そのものは @metropolis さんの回答に書かれた内容が良いと思われるので、@fana さんのコメントのように AddArray() で行うべき処理に合わせて調整してみてください。
- ちなみに講義・演習等の次の段階で示されるのかもしれませんが、今の while(1) ループでは Array用に定義した領域である 100個を超える数のデータが入力出来てしまいます。
  もちろん領域をオーバーフローするので入力したデータ数やその内容によっては異常な動作をする可能性が非常に高くなります。
  0入力チェックと共に入力データ数のチェックも行った方が良いでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。細かい部分を理由を含めて指摘してくださったおかげでなんとか解決しました。コメントしてくださった@kunifさん、@metropolisさん、@hataさん、@fataさん、@y_waiwaiさんありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

```
            if(Array[*data_num] < Array[*data_num--]){
            temp = Array[*data_num--];
            Array[*data_num--] = Array[*data_num];
            Array[*data_num] = temp;
```

ここで、data_num はマイナスになってしまい、Array[*data_num]はアクセス違反となってしまいますね

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NUM 100

void AddArray(int Array[MAX_NUM], int data_num);

int main(void) {
  int Array[MAX_NUM];
  int data, i;
  int data_num = 0;

  while (1) {
    printf("正整数");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    Array[data_num++] = data;
    AddArray(Array, data_num);
    if (data == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("入力された数字は順に");
  for (i=0;i<data_num-1;i++) {
    printf("%d,", Array[i]);
  }
  printf("%dです。\n", Array[data_num-1]);
}

void AddArray(int Array[MAX_NUM], int data_num) {
  int i, j, temp;
  if (data_num < 2) return;
  for (i=0;i<data_num;i++) {
    for (j=data_num-1;j>i;j--) {
      if (Array[j] < Array[j-1]) {
        temp = Array[j-1];
        Array[j-1] = Array[j];
        Array[j] = temp; 
      }    
    }
  }
}

// 正整数1
// 正整数3
// 正整数2
// 正整数0
//
// 入力された数字は順に0,1,2,3です。
```

Comment: 実際には回答された内容の方が良いと思いますが、質問には「プロトタイプ宣言ですが、下のコードの通りに書くよう言われました。」とあるので AddArray() の定義は変えてはならない可能性がありそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。AddArray()ですが定義は変えてはいけないと書いてありました。大変申し訳ありませんが、参考にはさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。